# undefined method 'status' for Twitter:Module in Ruby Script

Tags: ruby, twitter, rubygems

I think that this error might be releated with some configuration of my rvm and rubygems. I am running on ubuntu, the code runs properly in other machines, but not in mine.

I copied the code from the example in github, but for some reason its not working. I have tried both 1.8.7 and 1.9.2, and also rubygems 1.7 and 1.5. I don't know what else to try.

**Code**

```
require "rubygems"
require "twitter"
puts Twitter.status(27558893223).text
```

**twitter gem**

```
work/dump% gem list --local -d twitter
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
twitter (1.4.0)
Authors: John Nunemaker, Wynn Netherland, Erik Michaels-Ober, Steve
Richert
Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/twitter
Homepage: https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter
Installed at: /home/pdelgallego/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180

Ruby wrapper for the Twitter API
```

**Error**

```
1.rb:3:in <main>': undefined methodstatus' for Twitter:Module (NoMethodError)
```

**Ruby version**

```
ruby -v 
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i686-linux]
```

Any idea ?

Comment: What does Twitter.methods.grep(/st/) give you?

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter module requires some sub-modules, among them Twitter::Client.
method_missing is forwarded to Twitter::Client.

So I'd guess your Twitter module somehow does not find the correct Twitter::Client module.

What's the output of

```
ruby -e "require 'twitter'; c = Twitter::Client.new; puts c.respond_to?('status')"
```

Comment: the output is true. 

if I change to c.status() the output raise an ArgumentError.

    c.status(27558893223)
    ArgumentError: Invalid status action: 27558893223
 from /home/pdelgallego/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mbbx6spp-  twitter4r-0.4.0/lib/twitter/client/status.rb:34:in `status'
 from (irb):13